# WebDav how to check if folder exists?

Tags: c#, webdav

This is my current function below. Its used to create a folder in a document library in SharePoint but using web dav functionality, which is easier than MOSS stuff.

I need to find a way to determine reliably if the folder already exists... Notice now I am relying on that try catch, but this means that ANY protocol exception will not throw an error, so its not a reliable function. How can I check using web dav if a folder exists?

```
private void createFolderUsingWebDav(string siteAddress, string listAddress, string folderName)
        {
            //Check Databox Folder Exists
            string folderAddress = siteAddress + @"/" + listAddress + @"/" + folderName; 
            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(folderAddress);
                request.Credentials = wsLists.Credentials; // CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.Method = "MKCOL";
                response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

Essentially I want the unwrapped version of what this product achieves here: 
http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav/tutorial/exists.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do a PROPFIND on the url, you will get a 404 back if the folder does not exist.

Make the PROPFIND look something like this (only showing the relevant headers)

```
PROPFIND /yourfolder HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:">
   <prop>
      <resourcetype />
   </prop>
</propfind>
```

404 means the resource doesn't exist, 207 means it does.

Comment: 207, not 217. See RFC 4918.

To just check for the presence of a folder, you also want to only get the DAV:resourcetype property, not all properties (which can be much more expensive).

Comment: How can I practically implement this in C#?

Comment: I'm not a C# person, but I would expect it to be extremely similar to your MKCOL request. Just add the xml body and Content-Type header and you should be set.

Comment: I think, you should also add `Depth : 0` header for performance.

Comment: "404 means the resource doesn't exist" - or it can mean the server is still starting up.

Comment: @AdrianBaker if you are using a server that emits a 404 to indicate that the server is not ready to serve requests, then it's a buggy server. This is non-standard, don't do this.

Comment: Agreed - it’s Adobe’s AEM server, so yes it’s most definitely buggy. However 404s from apis without content are still ambiguous : it could mean the resource doesn’t exist, or it could mean you have the wrong host, wrong service path.

Comment: You're right. It's only an indicator by the server that on that server the resource doesn't exist. The fact that you get a 404 could be a side effect from another problem.

Answer (score 0):

PROPFIND is your friend: the DAV:resourcetype property (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.15.9) has a DAV:collection child element for collections. Just retrieve it using PROPFIND with DAV:allprop or DAV:prop (both described in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9).

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example... I need something I cam implement fairly quickly... thanks...

Comment: Protocol examples are in RFC 4918, Section 9.1.